# fseek - fails skipping a large amount of bytes?

Tags: c, fseek

I'm trying to skip a large amount of bytes before using `fread` to read the next bytes.
When size is small `#define size 6404168` - it works:

```
long int x = ((long int)size)*sizeof(int);
fseek(fincache, x, SEEK_CUR);
```

When size is huge `#define size 649218227`, it doesn't :( The next `fread` reads garbage, can't really understand which offset is it reading from.

Using `fread` instead as a workaround works in both cases but its really slow:

```
temp = (int *) calloc(size, sizeof(int));
fread(temp,1, size*sizeof(int), fincache);
free(temp);
```

Comment: The offset parameter wants a `long int` (not a `long long`)

Comment: @AlterMann, tried changing to `long int` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you get rid of the cast too?  Also what is the return value, you really should check it...

Comment: oops! you guys are right. I checked and once I change `x` into `long int` it overflows to `-1698094388` and ret from `fseek` is `-1`. What should I do? How come `fread` doesn't suffer from this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `sizoef(int)` is `4` and you are on a 32 bit system (where sizeof(long) is 4),

So 649218227*4 would overflow what a *long* can hold. Signed integer overflow is *undefined behaviour*. So you it works for smaller values (that's less than LONG_MAX).

You can use a loop instead to `fseek()` necessary bytes.

```
long x;
intmax_t len = size;

for(;len>0;){    
   x = (long) (len>LONG_MAX?LONG_MAX:len);
   fseek(fincache, x, SEEK_CUR);
   len = len-x;
}
```

Comment: great. I did `for (int k=0; k<sizeof(int); k++) fseek(fincache, (long int)size, SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: That will work as `649218227` wouldn't overflow a *long|* on a 32-bit system. But it's still a good idea to check it against `LONG_MAX`. If you change that value later or use the same code on a 16-bit system, you'll have problem.

Comment: @user4815162342 Actually `size` is a #define'ed value. So it doesn't have a fixed type. My code should have used a different variable as `size` is not a variable. But still the idea is same.

Comment: @user4815162342 The type of integer  literal doesn't have a fixed type. In the comparison, the two literal values will have a type depending on their ranks. `x` is long and is not assigned any value value >LONG_MAX. So the check is fine.

Comment: I switched my code to yours and now again fseek returns `-1` after several iterations... :(

Comment: @ihadanny It depends what types you use for the variable that you used for `size`. I have edited just to make use of a var. If the literal value itself (`#define size`) is too big that none of the standard integer types can hold it, then you'll have to change your approach.

Comment: You're right, my analysis was flawed. Still, it's good that your answer now makes it clearer that both overflow in calculation of `size` and the one in the call to `fseek` need to be handled. BTW calling `fseek` in a loop is a lovely hack, but unfortunately it doesn't scale for large seeks. In production code a function that takes `off_t` would be preferable.

Comment: wow, turns out that even when I thought it works, it returned -1 sometimes.. I'm giving up on fseek and returning to the good old fread slow approach.

Answer (score 1):

The `offset` argument of `fseek` is required to be a `long`, not a `long long`. So `x` must fit into a `long`, else don't use `fseek`.

Comment: nice guess. Tried to change to `long int` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Because `((long int)size)*sizeof(int)` is bigger than the maximum value allowed to be stored in a long. See `<limits.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Input guidance for fseek:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence)
```

> offset − This is the number of bytes to offset from whence.

You are invoking undefined behavior by passing a `long long` (whose value is bigger then the Max of `Long int`) to fseek rather then the required `long`.

As is known, UB can do anything, including not work.

Comment: Tried to change to long int and it still doesn't work

Comment: @ihadanny Does your size fit into a normal `long int`

Comment: In C, passing a `long long` to a function declared to accept `long` is not undefined behavior unless the number is outside the [LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX] range. Inside the range, the compiler will correctly cast the `long long` value to `long`.

Comment: @user4815162342 the value he is passing is outside of that, though. So he is invoking UB

Comment: Agreed. The amended answer no longer contains the erroneous general claim. (But it does contain an unclosed parenthesis.:))

Comment: @user4815162342 No more :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your platform's `int` is most likely 32-bit, multiplying 649,218,227 with `sizeof(int)` results in a number that exceeds `INT_MAX` and `LONG_MAX`, which are both 2**31-1 on 32-bit platforms. Since `fseek` accepts a `long int`, the resulting overflow causes your program to print garbage.

You should consult your compiler's documentation to find if it provides an extension for 64-bit seeking. On POSIX systems, for example, you can use [`fseeko`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fseek.html), which accepts an offset of type `off_t`.

Be careful not to introduce overflow before even calling the 64-bit seeking function. Careful code could look like this:

```
off_t offset = (off_t) size * (off_t) sizeof(int);
fseeko(fincache, offset, SEEK_CUR);
```

Comment: Do mind that input of fseek is a long int rather then a normal int.

Comment: @Magisch Good point. I've now amended the question to cover both the overflow when calling `fseek` and the overflow when calculating the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You may have to read it out if it's such a large number

```
 size_t toseek = 6404168;
 //change the number to increase it
 while(toseek>0)
 {
    char buffer[4096];
    size_t toread = min(sizeof(buffer), toseek);
    size_t read = fread(buffer, 1, toread, stdin);
    toseek = toseek - read;
 }
```